# Address Space Layout for a Multithreaded Linux Process

Tags: c, linux, layout, space, memory-address

I want to know the full detail of the address space layout of a multithreaded Linux Process for both 64 bit and 32 bit. Link to any article that describes it will be appreciated. And note that I need to know full details, not just an overview, because I will be directly dealing with it. So I need to know for example, where are the thread stacks located, the heap, thread private data etc...

Comment: Especially I want to know details about portion which are writable. For example I don't need to deal with the part of the address space that contains the code, since its not writable.

Comment: Do you know all details of no-threaded linux process, don't you? The difference between non-threaded and multithreaded is number and place of stacks.

Answer (score 8):

Thread stacks are allocated with `mmap` at thread start (or even before - you can set the stack space in `pthread_attr`s). TLS data is stored in the beginning of thread's stack. Size of thread's stacks is fixed, typically it is from 2 to 8 MB. Stack size of each thread can't be changed while the thread is live.  (First thread - running main - is still uses main stack at the end of address space and this stack may grow and shrink.) Heap and code is shared between all threads. Mutexes can be anywhere in `data` section - it is just a struct.

The mmap of thread's stack is not fixed at any address:

[Glibc sources](http://www.google.com/codesearch#xy1xtVWIKOQ/pub/glibc/snapshots/glibc-latest.tar.bz2%7CXP6Z3zoy3dk/glibc-20090518/nptl/allocatestack.c&q=ALLOCATE_STACK%20&exact_package=ftp://sources.redhat.com/pub/glibc/snapshots/glibc-latest.tar.bz2&type=cs&l=483)

```
 mem = mmap (NULL, size, prot,
                  MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_STACK, -1, 0);
```

PS modern GCC allows threads stack to be unlimited with [SplitStacks](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/SplitStacks) feature